# which interface to give during Ntop installation?

Tags: ntop

I get a eula window asking me to enter a comma-separated list of interfaces that ntop should listen on.  │
     I want to monitor my ethernet connection.what interface should i give?

[image: the eula screen]

Answer (score 1):

That depends on your system. You can get the interface name if you click on the Network Manager in your top panel and select Connection Information. Near the top, you'll see something like "Interface: Ethernet (eth0)". If that's the connection you want to monitor, you'll enter "eth0".